# How do I use a function with a structure variable in the main function in C in this case?

Tags: c, data-structures

When executed, it shows 'e' not defined. I'm not able to run the function 'search1' in this. Please while answering, also show how to make a function for adding an element from the user.(Periodic Table). Thanks for helping.

```
#include<stdio.h>  
#include<stdlib.h> 

struct element 
{
    int atno; 
    char *name; 
    char *symbol; 
    char *mn; 
    float bp; 
    char *state; 
}; 
int i=0,n=118; 
void search1(); 

int main() 
{
    struct element e[n]; 
    e[1].atno=1;
    e[1].name="Hydrogen";
    e[1].symbol="H";
    e[1].mn="Metal";
    e[1].bp=-252.879;
    e[1].state="Gas";

    e[2].atno=2;
    e[2].name="Helium";
    e[2].symbol="He";
    e[2].mn="Non-Metal";
    e[2].bp=-268.28;
    e[2].state="Gas";

    search1();
}

void search1()
{
    int a;
    printf("Enter the atomic number: ");
    scanf("%d",&a);

    if(a<1 && a>n)
    {
        printf("The element dosen't exist");
    }
    else
    {
        for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        {
            if (e[i].atno == a)
            {
                printf("Atomic Number = %d \nName = %c \nSymbol = %c \nMetal/Non-Metal = %c \nBoiling Point(deg C) = %f \nState at room temperature = %c\n",e[i].atno,e[i].name,e[i].symbol,e[i].mn,e[i].bp,e[i].state);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `e` is local to `main()`, it's not visible in `search1()`. You need to pass it as a parameter.

Comment: You need to review variable scopes in your textbook or tutorial.

Comment: But how ? Please write the code and tell

Answer (score 1):

when you define a variable in one function, it will be local variable of that function and 
be inside of that function stack and outside of that scope ,it will no longer be defined so you should pass this variable to other functions if you want functions to see your local variables ,but also note that if you call them by value then if you do any changes on them in those functions, they won't be changed out side of that function.

you can also define global variable ,if you don't want to pass them ,but this is not suggested ,because this way every function will have access to them, which can cause so much risk ,if you are not careful enough.

besides there are several other mistakes:

first ,we initialize `array` from `0` not `1`.

second to copy one `string` into another one ,you can't use `=` you should use `strcpy`.

then you haven't defined strings , you defined `char *` which is different.
In order to use it, you should first allocate memory for it, and if it is not what you want then define array of chars.

we don't print strings with `%c` we print them with `%s`

look

```
struct element
{
    int atno;
    char name[20];
    char symbol[20];
    char mn[20];
    float bp;
    char state[20];
};
int n=118,i=0;
void search1(struct element e[],int n)
{
    int a;
    printf("Enter the atomic number: ");
    scanf("%d", &a);

    if (a<1 || a>n)
    {
        printf("The element dosen't exist");
    }
    else
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            if (e[i].atno == a)
            {
                printf("Atomic Number = %d \nName = %s \nSymbol = %s \nMetal/Non-Metal = %s \nBoiling Point(deg C) = %f \nState at room temperature = %s\n", e[i].atno, e[i].name, e[i].symbol, e[i].mn, e[i].bp, e[i].state);
            }
        }
    }
}
int main()
{

    struct element e[n];
    e[0].atno = 1;// you could also use malloc to allocate memory for char* type
    strcpy(e[0].name , "Hydrogen");
    strcpy(e[0].symbol , "H");
    strcpy(e[0].mn , "Metal");
    e[0].bp = -252.879;
    strcpy(e[0].state ,"Gas");

    e[1].atno = 2;
    strcpy(e[1].name, "Helium");
    strcpy(e[1].symbol, "He");
    strcpy(e[1].mn, "Non-Metal");
    e[1].bp = -268.28;
    strcpy(e[1].state, "Gas");

    search1(e,n);
}
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210094/discussion-on-answer-by-hanie-how-do-i-use-a-function-with-a-structure-variable).

Answer (score 0):

## Problem:

> it shows 'e' not defined.

Of course, what is your `search1` searching for? `e`? Well, you should have a small read on the topic: Scope of Variables in C. Let [this](https://www.w3schools.in/c-tutorial/variable-scope/) be the starting point.

Now you know that your function is unaware of the existence of `e`. Because it is declared inside the `main` function and is invisible to the `search1` function.

## Solution:

You can pass `e` as an argument to your function so that `search1` has something to search for:

**Function Header:** `void search1(struct element e[n]);`

Your code should compile now.

But you may not get the desired output because your code does not print the results correctly. "%c" is used for `char` (characters like 'a', '2', '#', '\0'). It cannot be used to print strings (text like the name of your element, state, etc.). For strings, you should use "%s". Also, you can move the display code to a function and make it more readable:

```
void display(struct element e)
{    
    printf("\nAtomic Number             : %d", e.atno);
    printf("\nName                      : %s", e.name);
    printf("\nSymbol                    : %s", e.symbol);
    printf("\nMetal/Non-metal           : %s", e.mn);
    printf("\nBoiling Point (deg C)     : %f", e.bp);
    printf("\nState at room temperature : %s", e.state);
}
```

You can call this function as: `display(e[i]);`

> show how to make a function for adding an element from the user

Just like you hardcoded the elements in the main function, replace it with inputs using `scanf` inside your own `read` function. In this case, you should also have a counter to keep track of the number of elements in order to append the array. This counter will be needed by all the functions in your code, so make it global. If your project is not limited to this specific code snippet, then making it global is not a good practice. Pass this counter as an argument to the read, search, and display functions.